# do-until loop in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

Is there any latex code for "do-until" loop in algorithm2e package? Alternatively, is there a code for any "**while not**-do"? It does not look nice when I write this type of NOT condition inside while loop.

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   go back to the beginning of current section\;
  }
 }
 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: The `\Repeat` doesn't do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment `\Repeat` outputs repeat---until, but if someone wants to customize the words, it can be easily done as follows: `\SetKwRepeat{Repeat}{do}{until}`.

Hope this saves someone's time in future.